# Translate empty value in Symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, translate

I have a form with select box, and that field has an empty value property. I want to have it translated but adding translation_domain doesn't change anything.

```
<?php

namespace Devell\HowFolderBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class NoteType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('body', 'textarea');


    $categoryChoices = array();

    $builder->add('category', 'entity', array(
        'class'         => 'HowFolderBundle:Category',
        'empty_value'   => 'note.form.category.choose',
        'translation_domain' => 'HowFolderBundle'
    ));
    }

public function getName()
{
    return "note";
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should perfectely work as it's natively supported since > [[Form] made it possible to translate the empty value of Choice fields](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/2ce3cfad18691af93370be1b1d12be21a180ee19).

Then the problem is probably related to your translation configuration, Check if your [Translation component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) is enabled and well configured.

Comment: Other things translate as I want to. I have the messeges.en.yml which I use to type translated strings. Everything translates except the form value.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm really late with the answer but maybe it will be useful for someone. Check if your translation does not contain any special characters that YAML might try to parse. For example, this line would be parsed as array and, if it's the last line in the file, will not render any errors, etc.:

`inventory.select.default_text: [ please select ]`

It's as if translation is not found. What you need to do, is to quote your translation strings:

`inventory.select.default_text: '[ please select ]'`.